# android custom dialog view not fit in the dialog layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I create a alertdialog dynamically, it seems okay except that there are some space between the top of dialog view and the top of dialog layout margin. Check the pic would be more clear.

[image: dialog layout margin problem]

Is there some problem when I inflate the view? I just google it, but I cannot find any clues. Please help to modify the layout.

The dialog.xml is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_msg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="15sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/Ok"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code I dynamic create dialog

```
private AlertDialog createDialog(String title, String msg){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    ((TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title)).setText(title);
    ((TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_msg)).setText(msg);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    ((Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: i have checked your code its working fine. may be there is problem in theme settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `LinearLayout`'s width and height from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` and try.

Also try this

`dialog.setView(dialogView,0,0,0,0);` after calling

`final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();` in your method

Comment: Its still not wroking.  I've tried fill_parent, it failed too.

Comment: @ SripadRaj Place dialog.setView(dialogView,0,0,0,0); after calling
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); will let dialog be empty.
But after I change builder.setView(dialogView); to dialog.setView(dialogView,0,0,0,0); It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to show the bulider before return dialog.

builder.show();